# Copy/paste text from QClipboard freezes program

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget, pyside2, qclipboard

I have a QTableWidget that when a row is clicked, it selects all cells in that row. I am trying to add a "copy" functionality so that I can ^ctrl-c when row(s) are selected and paste into a text editor. However, with my current code, once i ^ctrl-c a row, the line that I copied keeps getting copied.

I have implemented a print statement in my method "read_clipboard" to see whether or not the line copied was read, and this is how I found out that the line keeps getting copied as if in an infinite loop.

None of the previous stack overflow questions on PyQt/Qt and QClipboard have been effective for me.

```
def __init__(self):
   super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
   self.setupUi(self)
   self.my_selector = self.my_tableWidget.selectionModel()

   # Where I detect the signal to call my "read_clipboard" method
   QtGui.QGuiApplication.clipboard().dataChanged.connect(self.read_clipboard)

   self.show()

def read_clipboard(self):
    selection = self.my_selector.selectedIndexes()
    if selection:
        print(selection)
        QtGui.QGuiApplication.clipboard().clear()
        QtGui.QGuiApplication.clipboard().setText(selection)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()  # Creates MainWindow object
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)
```

When I ^ctrl-c a row, the program prints the "selection" continuously as if it is in an infinite loop, I don't know how to stop it after it runs just once so that I can just copy that one line.

Comment: for some reason when it runs `read_cliboard` then it think that it changed data so it run function from `.dataChanged.connect()`. In `read_cliboard` you can disconnect it before coping to cliboard and connect again after coping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `dataChanged` signal in this way for two reasons:

- it will be called everytime the clipboard changes in the **whole** system;
- clearing the clipboard will obviously change its content, resulting in a recursive call to your `read_clipboard` method; you could obviously temporarily disconnect the signal as suggested by @furas, but the first problem will remain.

Also, you can't use a QItemSelectionModel for `setText`, as it expects a string.

A better solution is to override the keyPressEvent of a custom QTableWidget class, to catch it's "copy" action before the default implementation acts upon it:

```
class MyTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event == QtGui.QKeySequence.Copy:
            # set clipboard only if it's not a key repetition
            if not event.isAutoRepeat():
                QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard().setText(', '.join(i.data() for i in self.selectedIndexes() if i.data()))
        else:
            super(MyTableWidget, self).keyPressEvent(event)
```

Another similar possibility is to install an event filter to your table and check for its key events:

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.my_tableWidget.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.table and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress and event == QtGui.QKeySequence.Copy:
            if not event.isAutoRepeat():
                QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard().setText(', '.join(i.data() for i in self.table.selectedIndexes() if i.data()))
            # return True to ensure that the event is not actually propagated
            # to the table widget, nor its parent(s)
            return True
        return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(source, event)
```

Comment: Your codes have errors: 1) In the first code event is a QKeyEvent that I don't think can be compared with QtGui.QKeySequence.Copy. 2) In the second one you have the same error but also what happens if the Repaint event is sent before the QKeyEvent is sent?

Comment: @eyllanesc I used to check for QEvent.KeyPress and then do an `event.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.StandardKey)`, then I found similar examples and was very skeptical about it too, but I gave it a try and it actually seems to work fine. I'm on an old version of PyQt5 (5.7.1) which I can't upgrade right now, and it's possible that the implementation has changed in the meantime. What errors do you get?

Comment: I think you have been lucky because as you point out it makes no sense, I have not tested it but as it says: *better explicit than implicit*

Comment: How strange, it seems to work. Although in the second code it is called 2 times, I suppose this is for the QKeyPress and QKeyRelease.

Comment: I didn't say it makes no sense, but that I was skeptical :-) The more I think about it, the more I realize it does make sense. Also according to the sources that's how they [implement it](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#2336). You're right about the other call: I get it 3 times here: the 1st is a QEvent.ShortcutOverride after "c" is pressed, the 2nd a KeyPress, finally the release; strangely enough, if I release Ctrl before "c" there's no release event at all! Anyway, I'm going to edit it to ensure that it's called just for the keyPressEvent.

Comment: Qt defines [`operator==`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qevent.h.html#802) for `QKeyEvent/QKeySequence`. This was [documented in Qt4](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qkeyevent.html#operator-eq-eq-69), but it's missing in Qt5. I've reported it as a bug.

Comment: @musicamante I used the first method with the keyPressEvent and it worked. Thanks!