# How To Block Copy and Paste key in Pyqt5 Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am developing a desktop application which required to block copy and paste from the keyboard. I have to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> so that user cannot copy and paste in the QlineEdit Field from the keyboard.

Below is the code which I am using to capture control key. please tell me how I can block the event.

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Control:
            print("pressed control key")
```

my main app code which load after signin

```
ui,_=loadUiType(resource_path('main2.ui'))

class MainApp(QMainWindow, ui):

    def __init__(self,count,user_id,date):
        # super(QMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.count=count
        self.user_id=user_id
        self.date=date
        print(type(self.date))
        year,month,day=self.date.split('-')
        self.createdDate = QDate(int(year),int(month),int(day))
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Comment: You don't want to check for the Key_Control, but for key.text()=="C" (or similar) and then check event.modifier if the Control key is pressed.

Comment: @DovGrobgeld can you write code for this problem

Comment: You are assuming that Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V are copy and paste, which isn't necessarily true. For example, on a Mac, Ctrl would be replaced with the Cmd key. There's also the matter that copying and pasting can be done entirely with the mouse, no keyboard necessary.

Comment: @alamjamal Sir please read the SO rules: [ask] and [answer], in addition to passing the [tour]. If you want a more precise help then edit your post and provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry bro i am new here and don't know how to post code in comment

Comment: @alamjamal 1) When you provide code, don't just paste it and wait for the community to guess what it does, instead explain for example what variable the QLineEdit is, what is the QLineEdit that you want to prevent from being copied or pasted via the keyboard? 2) Please do not excuse yourself, you are no longer new to the site: you have been a part of SO for 4 years and also you should have read the links that happen to you, have you done it?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes i have read that link  . this was my 1st Q in SO community.

Comment: @alamjamal You still haven't answered my question (1), please don't get distracted and focus on your question.

Comment: @eyllanesc your code did not work when  I integrate them into my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the matches method of the QKeyEvent:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class LineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.Copy) or event.matches(
            QtGui.QKeySequence.Paste
        ):
        # or
        # if event in (QtGui.QKeySequence.Copy, QtGui.QKeySequence.Paste):
            return
        super().keyPressEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = LineEdit()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

The same can be done with an event filter:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Blocker(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__(widget)
        self._widget = widget
        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def widget(self):
        return self._widget

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.widget is obj and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.Copy) or event.matches(
                QtGui.QKeySequence.Paste
            ):
            # or
            # if event in (QtGui.QKeySequence.Copy, QtGui.QKeySequence.Paste):
                return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    blocker = Blocker(w)
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: While not "standard" (it's one of the few "very special" cases I know of, and possibly the only one that allows direct successful comparison of a QEvent with another object type) and **not documented**, key events can be *directly* compared with `QKeySequence.StandardKey` value: `if event in (QtGui.QKeySequence.Copy, QtGui.QKeySequence.Paste):`. I suppose that's due to the way QKeySequence and QKeyEvent are mapped, but that's just an ignorant's guess, and, as said, it's not standard nor documented, so it's possible that it won't work in future Qt releases, but I thought it was worth noticing.

Comment: (yes, I know, you already said it: [*better explicit than implicit*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260037/copy-paste-text-from-qclipboard-freezes-program#comment101024041_57262130) ;-) )

Comment: @musicamante Thanks, I did know that the "==" operator is available but as it is not documented I preferred not to point it out, the implementation is in: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/kernel/qevent.h?h=5.15.2#n840

Comment: Thank *you* for finding where the operator was declared :-) At least now I know where to look for for possible changes in the future. From the look of it, it seems like an internal convenience "shortcut" (pun intended): we cannot completely rely on it, but for the time being I'll keep using it, as I find it actually convenient - if used *wisely* and consciously, but it goes without saying...

Comment: @musicamante Those operators are [documented in Qt4](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qkeyevent.html#related-non-members), but not in Qt5. I posted a bug report about it back in 2019 ([QTBUG-77247](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-77247)), but I don't suppose it will be fixed any time soon...